# Узнать id элементов на текущей странице

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! У меня динамическая страница с постраничной навигацией. Выводится по 3 элемента на странице с обратным отсчетом по id. Мне нужно узнать id этих элементов текущей страницы, т. е. из базы вывелись в цикле элементы с id 1, 2, 3, их id есть в этой ссылке href='proverka_coda1.php?id=%s', теперь мне нужно эти id использовать (в списке). Пожалуйста, если напишете код, разъясните что делается, а то я недавно php занимаюсь. В коде еще пояснила. Спасибо.

Вот код:

```
Тут выводится три элемента (стихотворения) на странице:
<?php
    printf("<h2 align='center' style='font-size:15px'>%s</h2><div style='text-align:center'>%s
    <p style='color:#A6A6A6; font-size:14px'>автор: <b>%s</b><br> добавлено: <b>%s</b><br>
     <b><a style='color:#A6A6A6; font-size:14px' href='proverka_coda1.php?id=%s'>редактировать >></a></b></p></div><p align='center'>Рейтинг:<img src='images/%s.gif'></p>

    <form style='text-align:center' action='pereschet7.php' method='post' name='vv'>
        <p class = 'pvote' >1<input name='score' type='radio' value='1'>2<input name='score' type='radio' value='2'>3<input name='score' type='radio' value='3'>4<input name='score' type='radio' value='4'>5<input name='score' type='radio' value='5' checked>
      <input class='sub_vote' name='submit' type='submit' value='Оценить'>
      <input name='id' type='hidden' value= '%s'>
       <input name='cat' type='hidden' value='$cat'>
        </p>
    </form><br>", $myrow['nazv'], $myrow['text'], $myrow['title'], $myrow['date'], $myrow['id'], $r, $myrow['id']);

    }
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));

echo "<p align='left' style='font-size:15px; margin-bottom:20px'><b>КОММЕНТАРИИ:</b></p>";

    $result4 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM commentavtorskie WHERE page='$page' AND cat='$cat' ORDER BY id",$db);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result4) > 0)
    {
    $myrow4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

    do 
    {
    printf ("<div class='commentarii'><span style='float:left; margin-bottom:15px'>Добавил(а): <b>%s</b></span>
    <span style='float:right; margin-bottom:15px'>Дата: <b>%s</b></span>
    <p class='comment'>%s</p></div>",$myrow4["author"], $myrow4["date"], $myrow4["text"]);

    }
    while ($myrow4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4));

    }

    $result5 = mysql_query ("SELECT img FROM comments_setting",$db);
    $myrow5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5);

    ?>
```

Вот здесь в списке хочу выводить названия стихов с id, чтобы пользователь выбрал. Нужны id этих трех стихов, что вывелись выше. id хочу дальше в обработчике использовать, чтобы на почту пользователю приходило сообщение типа: "к вашему стихотворению добавлен комментарий". Как получить id?

```
<p align='left' style='font-size:15px'><b>ДОБАВИТЬ КОММЕНТАРИЙ:</b></p>
<form action="commentavtorskie.php" method="post" name="form_com">
<p><label>Ваше имя:  </label><input name="author" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30"></p>
<p><label>Текст комментария: <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="text" cols="31" rows="5"></textarea></label></p><p>Введите сумму чисел с картинки:<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<? echo $myrow5["img"]; ?>">&nbsp;
  <input name="pr" type="text" size="7" maxlength="5"></p>
  <input name="page" type="hidden" value="<? echo $page; ?>">
  <input name="cat" type="hidden" value="<? echo $cat; ?>">
<p><input name="sub_com" type="submit" value="Комментировать"></p>

</form>

</div>

 </div>

<? include ("blocks/footer.php"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Во первых, вот здесь неправильно:

```
 do 
    {
    printf ("<div id='commentarii'><span style='float:left; margin-
```

ИД в странице должно быт только 1! А вот классы сколько захотите.

2) брат контент по Ид элемента :

javascript:

document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML;

id вот так:

```
var getId = function(){
  alert(this.id);
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); // All divs

for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].onclick = getId;

}
```

[Ссылка на пример](http://jsfiddle.net/HJbvR/)

Comment: не знаю, не получается, разъясните, пожалуста, функцию, я не очень хорошо в этом разбираюсь.